# Perl Pod::WSDL: wrong return type

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I have a problem with Pod::WSDL perl module and didn't find an answer, yet...
I use a method like this:

```
=pod
=begin WSDL

_DOC
Method hopefully returning a string

 _IN parameter1 $string     The first STRING parameter
 _RETURN $string            Returns a string

=end WSDL
=cut

sub go {
 my ($this, $parameter1) = @_;
 return($parameter1);
}
```

The problem is this: calling this method with a string (say:

```
go("abc");
```

), everything is fine.

Calling it with a value which is a number (say:

```
go("123");
```

), produces a return type of "xsd:int", instead of "xsd:string", as I would expect from "_RETURN $string"...
This is the full SOAP Envelop built, if it can help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><goResponse xmlns="http://192.168.10.21/TestService"><s-gensym3 xsi:type="xsd:int">1</s-gensym3></goResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

---

Returning:

```
return("" . $parameter1);
```

doesn't help. Returning something like this:

```
return(" " . $parameter1);
```

does help, but it's not what I want to return... :-)

Comment: Sounds like a bug or misfeature in POD::WSDL.  I would suggest reporting it as such.  Use https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Pod-WSDL or email bug-Pod-WSDL@rt.cpan.org

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just reported as a bug on rt.cpan. However, due to the severity of the problem, I suppose this module is scarcely used and mantained at least, so I suppose I will soon migrate to something else (like WSDL::Generator, or ... any suggestion?)

Comment: Yet unassigned, on rt.cpan...